# simple_form - prevent Time.now from generating a date-picker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Good sirs,

I got this line in my `minimal_form_for` block

```
<%= f.input :start_time, :input_html => {:value => Time.now} %>
```

which promptly generates a date-time-picker inside the form.

If I only want to ***show*** Time.now (or any other data) and have the form submit it in its hash, ***without*** making the field editable, what is the syntax?

The simple_form wiki had [a somewhat confusing entry](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Create-an-%22input%22-just-for-displaying-attribute-value) about redefining the input, but I had no luck in defining a new `f.non_editable_input` for me to use alongside the standard `f.input`. What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's simple
you just need add more html attribute like this

```
<%= f.input :start_time, :input_html => {:value => Time.now}, :disabled => true %>
```

Comment: Thank you sir - that works for all my other attributes except the Time.now field (which retains an ugly grayed out version of the date-picker. I'm thinking just display Time.now inside a <span> while sending it along in parallel with a hidden field.